# Use own/custom field inside Craft Table

Tags: craft3, modules, custom-field, table-field

I made my own, fairly simple field inside a Module for Craft 3.x.

[image]

What settings do i need to define to make it usable inside a table?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just can't: allowed field types seem to be hardcoded in `craft\fields\Table::getSettingsHtml()`.

See https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/Table.php#L215 for details.

You might create a CustomTable field that inherits the `Table` class and overrides its `getSettingsHtml()` methods to allow you custom field type, but that seems overkill. It may be easier to just use a matrix field instead of a table field.